# Yii2 set hidden input as current user id

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to set a form field as the id of the current logged in user using Yii2. 
This is my form:

```
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin();?>

        <?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'id', array('value'=> $model->getId()));?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'offer_type_id') ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'offer_description')->textArea(['rows' => 6])  ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'start_date') ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'end_date') ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'store_id') ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

and this is my model:

```
use Yii;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;
/**
* This is the model class for table "tbl_offers".
*
* @property integer $offer_id
* @property integer $id
* @property integer $offer_type_id
* @property string $offer_description
* @property string $start_date
* @property string $end_date
* @property integer $store_id
*/
class TblOffers extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
   public static function findIdentity($id)
  {
     return static::findOne($id);
  }

 public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
 {
     return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
 }

 public function getId()
 {
     return $this->id;
 }

 public function getAuthKey()
 {
     return $this->authKey;
 }

 public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
 {
     return $this->authKey === $authKey;
 }

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'tbl_offers';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [[ 'id', 'offer_type_id', 'offer_description', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'store_id'], 'required'],
        [[ 'id', 'offer_type_id', 'store_id'], 'integer'],
        [['start_date', 'end_date'], 'safe'],
        [['offer_description'], 'string', 'max' => 8000]
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'offer_type_id' => 'Offer Type ID',
        'offer_description' => 'Offer Description',
        'start_date' => 'Start Date',
        'end_date' => 'End Date',
        'store_id' => 'Store ID',
    ];
}

    public function getofferId()
{
    return $this->getPrimaryKey();
}

}
```

Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong? When I try to save the form once I've filled in the rest, the form doesn't submit (and I'm guessing this is because the ID field hasn't been filled in) Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Why are you implementing the `IdentityInterface`, if you don't mind me asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` is null since you are setting it to `$this->id` which has not been set anywhere.

You can get the currently logged in user using `Yii::$app->user->id`. As such there is no need for the hidden field or the rules for `id`. You can just set the `id` manually using `ActiveRecord::beforeSave()`:

```
public function beforeSave($insert = true) {
    if ($insert) 
        $this->id = Yii::$app->user->id;
    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```

Comment: In answer to your question on the original post, I'm new to yii and i've been trying a variety of different ways to get the user id. So do I remove the identity interface from the model, and in the view add the above function? or do i add that function to the model?

Comment: Finally got it working. after using your code above I was still getting issues where it wasn't grabbing the ID value as the $model would still be null. I changed the $model to $this and it all worked gloriously! Thanks for you help!!